# Set Value of Dijit.Form.Textarea

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have a dijit dialog that contains a form that I want to auto-populate. I can get the dialog to display with the form in it, but I have been unable to set the value of a text area within the form. Here is the div that houses the html.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="formDialog" title="Form Dialog" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="desc">
                Description:
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>

        <textarea id="desc" name="desc" dojoType="dijit.form.Textarea" style="width:200px;"></textarea>
```

SAVE
                
                
                    CLOSE

I can get this to display just fine by doing

var formDlg = dijit.byId("formDialog"); 
formDlg.show();

But the issue I have is setting the value of the textarea called "desc". I have tried multiple things, but I know I need to

```
var test = dijit.byId("desc");
```

but if I set any property of test, such as

```
   test.value = "foo";
   test.textContent = "foo";
   test.innerHTML = "foo";
   test.srcNodeRef = "foo";
```

The value is never saved and displayed inside the textarea. Is there a trick to doing this? Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
var test = dijit.byId("desc");
test.set("value", "foo");
```

..should do the trick, I think. Most widgets in Dojo use the `set` method (formerly `attr`) to set property values, instead of manipulating them directly like you've tried to do. You can also set multiple properties in one go by passing an object:

```
var test = dijit.byId("desc");
test.set({"value": "foo", "name": "someName"});
```

Comment: That's odd, `setValue` is deprecated in favor of `set("value", ..`. I guess perhaps you're using an older version of Dojo? Oh well, glad I could help :-)

Comment: Using `set()` does not change the input's value in the DOM, but dojo's internal value for that element. You can verify that by using `get()`. Looking in the element selector will not help :/

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `dijit.byId("txtAreaMytextarea").set("value", "somevalue")` does not work with `TextArea` but works with other dijit types when you use Dojo 1.6 and use `dijit.form.SimpleTextarea` as `TextArea`. The function `setValue("")` also doesn't work.

If this happens to you, try using `dojo.byId` instead of `dijit.byId` and just setting value by doing

```
dojo.byId("txtAreaMytextarea").value = "somevalue";
```