# Why is FilteringSelect in declarative dijit form causing invalid submit?

Tags: forms, dojo, dijit.form

Help me understand this.

Isn't `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` (extended from `ValidationTextBox`) supposed to have property `required = false` by default?

Why is it that simply including a FilteringSelect in a declarative form like so below automatically results in `dijit.form.Form.isValid() == false`?

Even manually setting the filteringselect's `required` prop to false results in an invalid form submit. I feel like there's something I'm missing here.

I'm Using dojo toolkit version 1.6.1.

```
<!-- form.html -->

<form id="form" dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="friend">
        <select name="friend" id="friend-input" dojotype="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" id="submit-input" value="Submit" label="Submit" dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>


/* form.js */

dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");

dojo.ready(function() {
var form = dijit.byId("form");
var friendInput = dijit.byId("friend-input");
friendInput.required = false;

dojo.connect(form, "onSubmit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (form.isValid()) {
        alert("Ready to submit data: " + dojo.toJson(form.get("value")));
    } else {
        alert("Form is not valid.");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Does this work? `friendInput.set("required", false);`

Comment: Appears to work, yes. Thanks. I think my gap in understanding was believing that get() and set() were methods to operate on the underlying tag's attributes, and not all the properties of a widget. I see now that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107722/set-value-of-dijit-form-textarea) was getting at the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Like Frode mentioned, we need to set the required to false.
But, lots of fields might be used. Not a good idea to set 'required' for each, in the dojo.ready section.

```
<select name="friend" id="friend-input" 
             dojotype="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" required="false"></select>
```

The better way is to mention it as attribute in the html itself. Let me give an example why it is better.

If the field is included in a tab, and if the tab is refreshed on certain actions, the html will be arsed again. So, in that scenario, the required will be true again for that field. So, therefore, provide it in the html declaration of the widget itself to avoid these scenarios.